# Primefaces, Trigger command button click oncomplete

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is it possible to trigger a click on commandButton on `oncomplete` attribute of another commandButton?

Like this :

```
<p:commandButton value="save" action="#{myBean.save} oncomplete="trigger button2" />
<p:commandButton value="print" ajax="false" action="#{myBean.print}" widgetVar="button2" />
```

Second button is with attribute `ajax="false"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the answer was in my question -.-

```
<p:commandButton value="save" action="#{myBean.save}" oncomplete="$('#print').click();" />
<p:commandButton value="print" id="print" ajax="false" action="#{myBean.print}" />
```

Save the form, then trigger button2 click.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `p:remoteCommand` as :

```
<p:remoteCommand name="callButton2" action="#{myBean.print}" />
```

Then in your `button-1`

```
<p:commandButton value="save" action="#{myBean.save} 
 oncomplete="callButton2()" />
```

Now if you press Save, on complete It'll call print method.

Remember you should have `p:remoteCommand` inside the `form`.

Comment: I think p:remoteCommand does an ajax call right? I need a non-ajax post in my second commandButton :/ (exporting a pdf)

Comment: You didn't mention in your question. Try to give as much as information as possible.

Comment: Edited my question, second button was with attribute ajax="false"

Comment: Thx Makky, that's a great trick to get a post callback function server-side in order to let primefaces completes its process and only applies rendering finishes afterwards. You've just saved my day!